# How do I sort through list elements in html scraped from beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape html data and have successfully located the data I am trying to grab. The issue is what I am trying to scrape is li elements that do not have a class or id to find them out of several others on the page, so I located the ul element they are found under from its class. So I have the ul with the li elements I need saved to variable name record, but when I print record.li.text I only get the first li element and haven't figured out how to get the other li elements in the ul. Any help is appreciated

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
record = soup.find("ul", class_="ClubhouseHeader__Record")
print(record)
```

has the output

```
<ul class="ClubhouseHeader__Record"><li>64-98</li><li>3rd in AL Cent</li></ul>
```

while

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
record = soup.find("ul", class_="ClubhouseHeader__Record").li.text
print(record)
```

has the output

```
64-98
```

I would like the output to be

```
64-98
3rd in AL Cent
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. Simply utilize `BeautifulSoup.find_all`:

```
r = [i.text for i in soup.find("ul", class_="ClubhouseHeader__Record").find_all('li')]
```

Output:

```
['64-98', '3rd in AL Cent']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could target the desired `li` elements in one go with a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for li in soup.select("ul.ClubhouseHeader__Record li"):
    print(li.get_text(strip=True))
```